# Dropdown menu in oop php

Tags: php, oop, drop-down-menu

Im trying to create simple dropdown menu with numbers(0,1,2) as values.
To make it easy for a start I set selected value as number 2. No errors coming up,
dropdown box is there but no value displayed. What am I doing wrong. Please help

```
 <?php
class pulldown {

    function setName($name)         { $this->name = $name; }    // sets name of        
    //select field

    function setSelected($selected) { $this->setSelected=$selected; }

    function showSelected() {

        printf ("<select name='%s'>", $this->name);

             foreach( $this->lookupTable as $key => $val )
             {
                if($this->selected == $key ){
                  echo "<option select='selected' value='$key'>$val</option>";

                }else {
                  echo "<option value='$key'>$val</option>";

                }

             }

        echo" </select>";

     }

    private $lookupTable;
    private $selected;
    private $name;

}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////

class numbers extends pulldown {

    function __construct () {

        $this->setName('numbers');
        $this->setSelected("0");

        ///this are the numbers available to select
        $this->lookupTable = Array (
            "0" => "zero",
            "1" => "one",   
            "2" => "two"  
        );
    }

}


$mynumbers = new numbers();
$mynumbers->setSelected("2");

//$myresellers = new myresellers();
?> 
<html>
<form action="pullDown.php" method="post">
    <table width="1000" border="0" align="center">
    <td>
    <?php $mynumbers->showSelected(); ?>
    </td>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: `$this->setSelected=$selected;private $selected;` You've got the wrong variable name there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the wrong variable in your setter. You need to use selected instead of setSelected.

```
function setSelected($selected) { $this->selected = $selected; }
```

Comment: I see now that you are using the wrong HTML syntax. Try use **selected=selected** instead of **select=selected**.

Comment: That didn't help either

Comment: I'm sorry. Third mistake is that you are trying to access a private property. Change **private $lookupTable;** to **protected $lookupTable;**